# Arduino + Android USB Host API = faulty packages

Tags: android, api, usb, arduino, host

I'm trying to interact with my [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) from my Android tablet running 4.0.3 and got everything working using the Android USB Host API, which means I can send data over USB to the board and read it there via `Serial.read()` successfully.

Now I'm trying to implement a feedback functionality, which means the other way around, sending from the Arduino Uno and reading on the tablet. This works also quite well using `Serial.write()`, but I got a little problem: Sometimes, there are no bytes transferred and some other times, only some of them, so the content I'm sending is cut in half. How do I fix this?

I'm asssuming the Serial port has some issues sending all of the data. Should I perhaps change the baud-rate which is currently at 9600?

Here's the code on the Android side:

```
byte[]data = new byte[1024]; //Bigger size just to make sure...
int returnLen = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN,data,data.length,500); //epIN is the`
```

On the Arduino side a simple

```
Serial.write(5);
```

is used.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code and also the data for which it is failing? Otherwise this question is too vague.

Comment: Simply trying to transfer small amounts of data (like never more than 10 bytes). Added the code as a edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read()` behavior you are seeing is working as intended: sometimes, fewer bytes will be available than the amount you want.  It's very similar to [standard POSIX read() syscall behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_%28system_call%29):

> "It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now [..]"

Your application needs to handle this possibility.  A common technique is to keep track of how many bytes you have read, and perform successive `read()` calls, accumulating bytes until you have the number desired.

Finally, consider using [usb-serial-for-android](https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/), an open source library implementing FTDI and CDC (Arduino) USB drivers.  Though it doesn't specifically deal with this application-level issue, it may save you trouble elsewhere, and has an active mailing list.